# SetCookie not working for a specific cookie on Windows Phone

Tags: php, ipad, windows-phone-7, cookies, setcookie

I have a website that requires a login. The logins are managed by an authentication token that is assigned to the target device (with a few others), but for some reason, its not working on Windows Phone. I have tested it on iPhone and all desktop browsers and it works on all of them.

I set it to show me the set cookies, and it is showing all the other cookies that have been set, except for the auth token cookie.

I tried changing the cookie name (to see if there was a collision with some redundant code running) but that didn't work (still working on desktop browsers).

I had placed a piece of code to detect the setcookie function call, which told me it was being called correctly. In the same code path of the login and setcookie I did a var_dump of the $_COOKIE then too and it showed that the token had been temporarily sent.

The code does contain the ability to detect a mobile browser, but it is unused (outside of a few small parts of the template engine).

An additional note about the code is that from the start, right up till the end, the output buffer is enabled, and only printed at the end of the code.

What else can I do to try to find the cause of the problem, or what could be causing the problem specifically for Windows Phone.

**EDIT**

I have just tested it on an iPad, and it is also not working. Very strange as it works on normal iPhones and the Safari browser.

**EDIT**

I have installed a server (AMPPS) on a computer on my LAN running the site (with the same db) and the login function works correctly.

In addition, during my tests, on the mobile (on the live version), the user is redirected to the users only page, but the cookie is not detected, and the user is returned to the sign in page. Other cookies are, but the auth token is not.

All of the cookies are set in the same way, with an expiry of time() + 3600, and the path set to '/'

Comment: Do you see the same behavior from within the [Windows Phone 7 Emulator](http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/how-to-install-and-use-the-windows-phone-7-emulator)?  Might be a bit of a bear to install...

Comment: I did try that earlier, but since my install of windows 8, it has not been working so well. Especially since the first time I installed it, it forced my laptop to rollback. But I was having some issues with other software, so I will try again and let you know

Answer (score 0):

I think I have fixed it. The code included some IP validation for the tokens, but for some reason, on those devices, the IP (returned from `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`) is `127.255.255.255`, which was incorrect. Not sure why it was doing that instead, but I have amended it so that the IP is not taken into consideration for invalid ips (such as 127.255.255.255) and it is working now.